# How do I add custom plugins to ckeditor4-vue?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, ckeditor, ckeditor4.x

I have some custom plugins that are made for the base ckeditor 4 and I want to add them to the ckeditor4-vue for a new project that I working on. How should I integrate them with the vue ckeditor?

I already have a config file from my original work calling the plugins and how they are integrated in the toolbar if that helps.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I just added their names on config

```
config: {
    toolbarGroups: this.toolbarGroups,
    height: this.height,
    language: this.language,
    extraPlugins: 'fakeobjects,iframe,sourcedialog',
    removePlugins: 'sourcearea'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution.
First you have to download ckeitor's source files. And specify "editor-url" where you specify the path to the local ckeditor's sources.
After that you can install any plugins as you do in simple ckeditor4.
Here is the the guid https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor4/latest/guide/dev_plugins.html

```
<ckeditor
   :editor-url="/js/ckeditor/"
   v-model="text"
   :config="{
      ...
      extraPlugins: 'iframe',
   }"
></ckeditor>
```